# Simple function that creates multiple emitters in Maya via Python

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm trying to create a function that creates emitters (emitting from objects), but I'm having trouble getting it to work with multiple objects at the same time.

I want `emitter1` to be connected to `nParticle1` and `emitter2` to `nParticle2`.

```
def particalWebSystem(webDensity,genoration):
    selectedObject = cmds.ls( selection = True )
    print selectedObject

    if len(selectedObject)==0:
        cmds.confirmDialog( title='Warning', message='Please select at least one object', button=['Close'], defaultButton='Close', cancelButton='Close', dismissString='Close' )

    if len(selectedObject)==1:
        print "<2"
    else:
        print ">2"
    emitting = cmds.emitter( selectedObject, n='emitter' )
    cmds.particle( n = 'nParticle#' )
    cmds.connectDynamic( 'nParticle#', em = 'emitter' )
    cmds.setAttr( "emitter.emitterType", 2 )

    cmds.setAttr( "nParticle#Shape.lifespanMode", 2 )
    cmds.setAttr( "nParticle#Shape.maxCount", webDensity ) 
    cmds.setAttr( "nParticle#Shape.lifespanRandom", generation )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck? You may benefit from how to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can create them individually but i'm struggling to make the function more versatile, allowing the user to select several object at the same time and for each of the selected to have its own emitter and nParticle. I'm not sure how to go about it :(

Comment: That's a restatement of what you've already told us. **Show** us your attempt at a solution.

Comment: Sorry, i've tried creating a loop that does the same job, but with the loop i get an error saying that it cant connect to the seconds emitter (I think it's a naming issue that i dont fully understand). I've also tried fixing the naming issue of the nParticle but with hope.

Comment: That's not showing. The code and error belong in your question.

Comment: I don't have the old code anymore, this is the only version that i have.

Comment: This is clearly not all the code, because nowhere does anything called `emitter1` or `nParticle1`, etc. actually exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this problem by making sure you use the name of the emitter you actually create -- you never know what name you'll really get because Maya will rename things. It's best to always capture the names of things you create and work on them instead of hoping you get the names you asked for.

This version makes a function and just calls it on every selected object.  It will silently do nothing for empty selections  it also returns the objects created in case you need them later.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def setup_emitter(source_object, maxcount, life_random):
    source_object, emitting = cmds.emitter( source_object, n=source_object + "_emitter" )
    particle, particleshape = cmds.particle( n = source_object + "_particles" )
    cmds.connectDynamic( particle, em = emitting)
    cmds.setAttr( emitting + ".emitterType", 2 )

    cmds.setAttr( particleshape + ".lifespanMode", 2 )
    cmds.setAttr( particleshape + ".maxCount", maxcount ) 
    cmds.setAttr( particleshape + ".lifespanRandom", life_random )
    return emitting, particleshape

for selection in cmds.ls(sl=True, type='transform'):
        print setup_emitter(selection, 100, 100) # your values here
```

Comment: Thank you very much and for the great tips for the future.